# Libspotify: There was an error generating your application key

Tags: spotify, libspotify

I have a premium Spotify account and I am trying to generate an application key to use with libspotify. I am doing this using the form here: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/request-key/, but the generation of the key always fails with a message "**There was an error generating your application key**".

I tried formatting my application name differently (e.g., spaces, no spaces, no dashes, etc), but the outcome is still the same.

Not sure if it's of any relevance, but I am logged in through facebook and my user name on the application form is shown as a number.

Is it possible that there is something wrong with my account ?

Thanks in advance,
-Kal.

Comment: can you share more details

Comment: What kind of detail are you looking for ? The form is pretty straightforward, there are two fields which need to be filled-in - the application name and a description.

Comment: I opened your link but that gave an error like "The server returned a "405 Method Not Allowed" ". Thats why I asked you for more details

Comment: Sorry about that. I just copied link off the navigation bar. In either case, the problem seems to be fixed now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Quality-of-service of spotify. Only questions about the spotify api are on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that something is up with the API key registration page. I've filed an internal bug report with the team that maintains that (I work at Spotify), and hopefully it'll be up and running soon! I'll update this answer if it turns out to be something other than that.

*Edit*: The error was on Spotify's website, everything seems to be working again.

Comment: Thank you Nick. I was able to generate the key now.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue again now. Do you know what it might be?

Comment: @DougJohnson probably the same thing, again. The developer site doesn't have the greatest uptime in the world, sadly.